# Windows BAT : test if a specific file is empty

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I would like to check if a specific file is empty in a windows .bat file. Here is my non working script :

```
set dir="C:\test"
set file="%dir%\fff.txt"

cd %dir%
if %file%%~zi == 0 exit
ftp -s:"%dir%\ftp.action"
exit
```

Could you help me debug this please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or try it with

```
@echo off
set "dir=C:\temp"
set "file=%dir%\a.txt"

call :CheckEmpty "%file%"
goto :eof

:CheckEmpty
if %~z1 == 0 exit
ftp -s:"%dir%\ftp.action"
goto :eof
```

The main difference is that I use a function call and use the %~z1, as the modifiers only works for paramters like %1, %2..%9 or for-loop parameters like %%a ...

Comment: Thanks, that works ! I only had to remove the double quotes in the "set" commands but this was perfect.

Comment: The double quotes are neccessary for path/filenames with spaces or special characters

Comment: Well, spaces won't cause troubles for the `set` command. From all characters that are legal in file names I think only `&` and `^` could cause problems.

Comment: @Joey: Of course, you are right, but the quotes are also good to avoid trouble with invisble spaces at the line end, with quotes these spaces are ignored

Answer (score 5):

batch solution using file compare:

```
type nul > blank
fc myfile blank > nul
if errorlevel 1 echo myfile is not empty
```

Comment: The question is if a specific file is *empty*.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%A in ("myfile") do If %%~zA equ 0 echo myfile is empty
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    Const ForReading = 1

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\boot.ini", ForReading)


    Dim arrFileLines()
    i = 0
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
      Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
      arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
      i = i + 1
    Loop
    objFile.Close
```

Comment: What is this language ?
This doesn't seem to be simple Windows command line (.bat) ...

Comment: No, my mistake. its vbscript, you can make a .vbs file and paste it in.