# How to search a text file in batch for a specific symbol and alter the script depending on the result

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a command that allows me to insert a check of a text file for a very specific symbol  (’) and I am having trouble. It is a single quotation mark and it occasionally is found on some folders that need to be zipped and when my batch zipper encounters the folder with the symbol in it's name, it just starts having a lot of problems and creates weird files. I am not going into a lot of detail, but I just need a way to (in plain terms) check if a text file contains the symbol (’) and if it does, send the script to an error line (just something to indicate the symbol was found, like "echo error found"). And if not, then just send it to the rest of the script...

Like FINDSTR "’" dirlist.txt
if found goto err else goto resume
I know that is very incorrect but you get the idea.

Here is what I have so far and I still have made no progress getting it to work:

```
findstr /i /c:"’" C:\ACFZ\FORZIP\dirlist.txt >2
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto LABEL0) else (goto LABEL1)

:LABEL0 
msg %username& "An invalid symbol has been found. Remove any single quotation marks (’) from the folder names and try again. If unsure, simply remove anything that looks like an apostrophe."
pause
goto ERROR

:LABEL1
echo No errors found, continuing
pause
goto ZIPSTART

:ERROR
echo an error was found, exiting...
pause
goto EXIT
```

It always ends up saying no errors, even though the file has the symbol in it.

Here is the text file I need to search (dirlist)

```
2082708  Amboy Bank
2082712  Cavender’s
2082736  Elizabeth Board of Education
2082763  Tri-Valley Developmental Services  LLC
2082773  Vector Management
```

Comment: Make sure the path to your file is correct, and make sure it has the content you think. Your code should work, although you shouldn't need so many GOTO statements. Also, your `>2` looks wrong. I suspect you want something like `>nul 2>nul` instead, but that has nothing to do with your stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I finally got it working right... Thanks to Harvey, I used the method of outputting any results to a separate file, and then checking that file for contents. Which actually works great, because if it finds an issue, it will show you the full name of the problem folder(s) so you can easily fix it.

Here is the snippet of the working part:

```
findstr "'" C:\ACFZ\FORZIP\dirlist.txt > error.txt
findstr "." error.txt >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO POPUP 
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO ALLCLEAR
```

and here it is with a bit more detail:

```
CD C:\ACFZ\FORZIP
DIR /AD /B /ON >dirlist.txt

Echo Checking for errors in folder names...
ping -n 3 localhost >nul

REM that is not an apostrophe!
findstr "'" C:\ACFZ\FORZIP\dirlist.txt > error.txt
findstr "." error.txt >nul
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO POPUP 
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO ALLCLEAR

REM Errorlevel 0= Something found, 1= nothing found

:POPUP 
color cf
msg %username% "An invalid symbol has been found. Remove any single quotation marks (’) from the folder names and try again. If unsure, simply remove anything that looks like an apostrophe."
goto ERROR

:ALLCLEAR
echo No errors found, continuing...
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
goto ZIPSTART


:ERROR
echo An error was found in the following folder name(s) below:^


findstr "." error.txt

echo. 
Echo Remove any symbols from the above folder name(s)
echo within your completed folder and try again.
Echo This program will now exit.
pause
goto EXIT


:ZIPSTART
REM Zip contents of each directory
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (dirlist.txt) do (
  CD "%%a"
  wzzip "C:\ACFZ\ZIPPED\%%a.zip"
  CD..
)
```

Glad I was able to fix this. I guess WinZip goes really crazy from that quotation mark. The reason I needed this was I wrote this batch script (there is more to it than what I have above, as this was the part I needed to work on) to automate the zipping and backup process at my work, so that the folders for the month's jobs are zipped up and then copied onto the server for archive. It was a pain to manually do it, so with this I can just do it all in one step.

Oh and yeah the errorlevel issue was I did not have it entered correctly. I did not space them over to the right.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

%error_level% indicates the status of the execution which always successful (0) unless you pass in wrong arguments (e.g. try run findstr without argument or with a wrong file name).

In your case, you need to examine the output (messages printed on the screen) of findstr. One approach is to rely on the fact that nothing is printed on the screen if findstr finds no string matched the search. For example:

```
set found=""
findstr "'" C:\ACFZ\FORZIP\dirlist.txt > findresult.txt
call:CheckEmptyFile findresult.txt found
if "%found%" EQU "FOUND" (
    echo An invalid symbol has been found
) else (
    echo No errors found, continuing
)

REM your execution goes here

REM Clean up
del findresult.txt
goto :eof

:CheckEmptyFile
if %~z1 == 0 (
  set "%~2=NOTFOUND"
) else (
  set "%~2=FOUND"
)
goto :eof
```

(Reference: [Windows BAT : test if a specific file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483960/windows-bat-test-if-a-specific-file-is-empty))